# How to check all conditions before executing aftermath

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a live validation function. The problem is that the aftermath of the conditions in the function executes executes before the last part is met. The entry validation indicator should not turn green until the conditions are met, however this is not the case.

The indicator turns green after the third condition is met. It should not,  until all conditions are met. Any suggestions on how I can solve this problem.

My code looks like below.

```js
$(function() {

  // Pre-define extensions
  var xTension = ".com .net .edu";

  $("input").keyup(function() {

    // Check the position of "@" symbol
    var firstLetter = $(this).val().slice(0, 1);
    var lastLetter = $(this).val().slice(-1);
    var userXs = "No";

    // User provided extension
    var userX = $(this).val();
    userX = userX.substr(userX.indexOf(".") + 0);

    if (xTension.indexOf(userX) > -1) {
      if (userX != "") {
        userXs = "Yes";
      } else {
        userXs = "No";
      }
    } else {
      userXs = "No";
    };

    if ($(this).val().indexOf("@") > -1 && (firstLetter != "@") && (lastLetter != "@") && (userXs != "No")) {
      $("#input-status").removeClass("red").addClass("green");
    } else {
      $("#input-status").removeClass("green").addClass("red");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.rack {
  width: 250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#input-status {
  width: 1px;
  height: 3px;
  with: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 2s;
}

input {
  width: 230px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

#input-status.green,
#input-status.red {
  width: 235px;
  background: darkGreen;
  transition: all 2s;
}

#input-status.red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rack">

  <h1>Live Validat.ion</h1>

  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter email address">
  <div id="input-status">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What arguments? The argument list in all function definitions in the code snippet is empty ..?

Comment: General comments: Use boolean values for true/false, not strings. There's no need for `+ 0` after `indexOf()`.

Comment: Use an array instead of a string for `xTension`.

Comment: @Barmar - Thank you very much,  I will adhere to that advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `xTension` an array, not a string. If the user types `user@foo.c`, `userX` will be `.c` and this will be matched by `indexOf()` with the string, since there's nothing that forces it to match whole words. When you do this, you no longer need to check whether `userX` is an empty string.

I've made a few other simplifications to the code:

1. Instead of getting the first and last characters, just test the position of `@` against appropriate limits.
2. No need for `+ 0` after `indexOf()`.
3. Don't keep calling `$(this).val()`, put it in a variable.
4. User a boolean variable for `userXs`.

```js
$(function() {

  // Pre-define extensions
  var xTension = [".com", ".net", ".edu"];

  $("input").keyup(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();

    // User provided extension
    userX = val.substr(val.indexOf("."));

    userXs = xTension.indexOf(userX) > -1;
    atPos = val.indexOf("@");
    if (atPos > 0 && atPos < val.length - 1 && userXs) {
      $("#input-status").removeClass("red").addClass("green");
    } else {
      $("#input-status").removeClass("green").addClass("red");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.rack {
  width: 250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#input-status {
  width: 1px;
  height: 3px;
  with: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 2s;
}

input {
  width: 230px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

#input-status.green,
#input-status.red {
  width: 235px;
  background: darkGreen;
  transition: all 2s;
}

#input-status.red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rack">

  <h1>Live Validat.ion</h1>

  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter email address">
  <div id="input-status">

  </div>
</div>
```